# vim search and append/modify

Tags: text, vim, replace

Is there a way to search for a text in vim and then modify, not just overwrite said text? i.e. if each occurrence matches certain pattern, I would like to replace each occurrence with unique text, partly based on characters next to occurrence the text that matches the pattern.

Specifically speaking, I'd like to do the following: 
I'd like to replace text that matches the pattern `/\*.png` with `/\*.png alt=* title=\*` where `*` is the text that varies in each case.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use regex if the text is static or already in the line that should be replaced. Please specify the text to be used for search & replace. Example is "filename.png" to "filename.png alt="filename" title="filename". This can also be achieved with sed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the results with parts of the match by using submatches. For instance, say you have the following html:

```html
<img src="foo_one.png" />
<img src="bar_two.png" />
```

You can run this command:

```
:%s/"\(.\{-}\)\.png"/"\1.png" title="\1" alt="\1"/g
```

The `.\{-}` will match "any number of characters before the `.png` part, non-greedily" ([`:help /\{`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2f%5c%7b)), and the brackets around it, `\(` and `\)` mark it as a captured group that will then be used in the substitution as `\1` (the first captured group). Running this gives you:

```html
<img src="foo_one.png" title="foo_one" alt="foo_one" />
<img src="bar_two.png" title="bar_two" alt="bar_two" />
```

Now, if you need a more complicated substitution, like turning the filename into a human-readable string, you could use the `\=` substitution flag to replace the string with any expression, like a function call. For instance, here's what we could run on the above text:

```
:%s/title="\zs\(.\{-}\)\ze"/\=lib#CamelCase(submatch(1))/g
```

This uses two Vim-specific patterns: `\zs` and `\ze`. Those are "match start" and "match end". The thing that will be searched for is the entire pattern, `title=...`. However, what will be replaced is *only* between `\zs` and `\ze`. This makes it easier to use the result of `lib#CamelCase` as a direct replacement.

Note that you don't need the `\(`/`\)` brackets this time around, because you can just use `submatch(0)` for "the entire match":

```
%s/title="\zs.\{-}\ze"/\=lib#CamelCase(submatch(0))/g
```

The function `lib#CamelCase` is my own function that's implemented like so:

```
function! lib#CamelCase(word)
  return substitute(a:word, '_\(.\)', '\U\1', 'g')
endfunction
```

You can write any function that takes some input and returns a replacement string, doing whatever you need.

---

I'm not sure what your level of experience is with both Vim and regular expressions, so it's hard to give specific advice, and Vim substitutions are a big topic. I can recommend you read up on these help topics:

- [`:help pattern-overview`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#pattern%2doverview)
- [`:help sub-replace-special`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#sub%2dreplace%2dspecial)
- [`:help sub-replace-expression`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#sub%2dreplace%2dexpression)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command line for that.
In Linux use sed.

```
sed -i 's/\.png/\.png alt=* title=*/g'
```

Here it is running a search on `.png`and replace by `.png alt=* title=*`.
You must use the backslash before the . because it's a special character.

Comment: Although I haven't made my original query clear enough (and your solution would probably work for that), It won't work for problem I've described as (as far as I am aware) doesn't utilize characters encountered prior to matching pattern, i.e. "*".

Comment: Please specifiy what you want.